# VBA - Insert Spilt Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

How can I separate 2 ranges at the same time?

The I am using currently (Thank you Vbasic) split only one of them:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cell Splitter")
    
Dim Descriptions() As String, dUpper As Long, d As Long
Dim r As Long, rString As String
    
For r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
rString = CStr(.Cells(r, "K").Value)

If InStr(rString, ",") > 0 Then
Descriptions = Split(rString, ",")
dUpper = UBound(Descriptions)

For d = dUpper To 0 Step -1
.Cells(r, "K").Value = Descriptions(d)
.Rows(r).Copy
If d > 0 Then .Rows(r).Insert

Next d

End If

Next r
```

I tried adding another range into the code but got a "400" error.

For example: I added `K:O` or `"K" & "O"` (Which doesnt work). I only wanted to process only 2 columns.

What I wanted it to do:

From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: How did you "added" "K:O"? What do you mean by that? Don't you want processing a column range, you want processing 5 columns?

Comment: I only wanted to process only 2 columns

Comment: What this processing should mean? I can see that your code copies or inserts rows... Isn't it possible to have the respective condition met for both columns? If so, how to proceed in such a situation? I alo asked **How did you "added" "K:O"?**

Comment: I have added the screenshot of what I wanted it to do. Thank you.

Comment: I replace `"K"` with `"K:O"` or `"K" & "O"`

Comment: You just have to repeat your code and apply it to `O`. I don't think you can process it at the same time cause you will have to take care of `Rows(r).Insert`.

Comment: What about the case when you have "A,B,C,D,E,F" in O:O? I mean, more elements in the array obtained by splitting... And you added a screen shoot, which is not bad, but saying "I tried adding another range into the code" must mean something true, easily to be shown. Not only words to prove somehow that you did something in that direction...

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted will not yield the result you want. As I mentioned in the comment, to add another column and apply the same code would need you to handle the inserting of rows. You may try this approach though.

```
Dim r As Range, lr As Long, v, i As Integer

With Sheet1
  'this code will parse your text the same way as your initial code
  'but you can repeat this code and just replace the column, in this case K to O
  'it will yield the same result but as I've said it will not happen in the same time
  'but instead one after the other
  lr = .Range("K" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set r = .Range("K2:K" & lr)
  For i = lr To 2 Step -1
    v = Split(.Range("K" & i), ",")
    .Range("K" & i).Resize(UBound(v)).Insert xlDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    .Range("K" & i).Resize(UBound(v) + 1) = Application.Transpose(v)
  Next

  ' repeat the exact code here but changing the column from K to whatever
End With
```

I hope this helps.